# Parse timezone name with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I want to parse date through moment.js (which is normally really easy) but my date contains the abreviation of the timezone, and the symbol `zz` do not work here. ([moment.js format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/))

```js
const str1 = "2020-08-28 13:15 CST";
const date1 = moment(str1, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm zz");
console.log(date1);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

As I am currently in UTC+2 timezone, it displays `2020-08-28T11:15:00.000Z` which corresponds to `2020-08-28 13:15:00 UTC+2`.

How could it recognize timezone abreviation ?

Comment: how would the final output will look like ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I just want to get a correct date object, the date should be `2020-08-28 18:15:00` in UTC time.

Comment: is the `str` always the same as above with CST at the end ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes, so the only way is to manually parse it and recognize timezone through `moment.tz(...)` ?

Comment: not really you do not need to worry about timezone since you are always converting it to UTC format ? Correct

Comment: @AlwaysHelping still need to recognize `CST` here (UTC-5) to appy the offset.

Comment: how come `13:15` -5 utc will become 18:15:00 ?

Comment: check this might help https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/445#issuecomment-278724892

Comment: @AlwaysHelping `13:15 CST (UTC-5)` is `18:15 UTC`

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
moment.utc('2020-08-28 13:15 CST').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm ZZ')
```

Comment: This is not working as I said. moment ignore `CST` and choose the current timezone of the user (for me UTC+2).

Comment: This displays `13:15` UTC time, this is not correct.